# Android automatic message sending

Tags: android, smsmanager

I need to develop an app that can send a message to specific number when launched. The specific message and phone number are provided in code so that app don't need to ask about the number or message.

```
protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        String phone_no ="123666666";
        String sms="Sms Text Here";
        SmsManager smsMgr= SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phone_no, null, sms, null, null);
```

as i tried this but it does not work

Comment: Are you getting any error or any log message?

Comment: Can you print your logcat error plz.